# How this for loop could be translated efficiently in vhdl using for generate statements?

Tags: vhdl

```
Hi guys i have this pseudo-code nested for loop (very simple to translate in C)

Input : x; //is an unsigned
Output : y;

val = 0;
for i = 0:n-1
  for j = 0:n-1
    if( ((x >> i) & 0x1) && ((x >> j) & 0x1) )
        val = val + x << (i + j);

y = val;
```

Is there a way to translate this using `for-generate` statments in VHDL? I'm aware of the fact that i could implement basically the same code using process and sequential for loop, but it is possible to do something similar using the for generate instead?

(my main issue is that there's no variable in concurrent statements).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use for loops within a process, you can use a variable.  This (translated into valid VHDL) should synthesise fine (assuming n is a constant or generic).

The resulting hardware may be large or slow, but the same would be true if you used generate statements. If it doesn't meet your size or speed goals, you get to play with clocked processes, and pipelining.

The obvious way to do it using `if ... generate` would be to make Val a 2-D array signal, which makes the "unrolling" into parallel hardware absolutely explicit. (or an n * n sized 1-D array) But that is more complex and error-prone than the simple process approach.

Comment: As far as i know, but i could be wrong, is that debugging signals is easier than debugging variable, this is why i'm asking for concurrent statement.

Comment: Anyway in summary you suggest that a simple process with a nested for cycle and a simple statement <code>val := val +...</code> is it better?

Comment: Yes I am suggesting the process is simpler and better. If I got stuck debugging, I would consider ALSO adding an array of signals and assigning `debug(j) <= val;` inside the inner loop. Either delete it when done, or hide it from synthesis with `--pragma translate off` or your tool's equivalent so that only simulation sees it.

Comment: Ok, let's try with that...